# Where to do tasks after the Phoenix app is launched?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

### Background

I am trying to use Phoenix LiveView to create a desktop application. Now, the only way to do this in a somewhat user friendly way (at least the only one I know off)  is to launch my Phoenix app/server in and then open browser window in the client's machine.

And this is the trick. Opening a browser's window in the client's machine.

### Code

By looking into some github repositories of other formidable Elixir programmers, I was able to fetch a piece of code that somewhat does the job.

**demo/lib/demo/application.ex**

```
defmodule Demo.Application do
  @moduledoc false

  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      DemoWeb.Telemetry,
      {Phoenix.PubSub, name: Demo.PubSub},
      DemoWeb.Endpoint
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Demo.Supervisor]
    result = Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)

    start_browser_command =
      case :os.type do
        {:win32, _} ->
          "start"
        {:unix, :darwin} ->
          "open"
        {:unix, _} ->
          "xdg-open"
      end

    if System.find_executable(start_browser_command) do
      System.cmd(start_browser_command, ["http://localhost:4000"])
    else
      Mix.raise "Command not found: #{start_browser_command}"
    end

    result
  end

  def config_change(changed, _new, removed) do
    DemoWeb.Endpoint.config_change(changed, removed)
    :ok
  end
end
```

This is supposed to first start the Phoenix App **and then** open the window.

### Questions

So, this code makes me feel a little uncomfortable for a specific reason: I was under the impression that the `start` function should be only for starting my phoenix server and not for anything else.

But then the question arises:

- If the `start` function's job is only to launch the app, then what is the *correct/best* place to do other tasks, like opening a browser's window or performing some preparation **after** the app is launched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, we use [`Application.start_phase/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#c:start_phase/3) invented exactly for that purpose.

If you want to run it asynchronously, just spawn another supervised `GenServer` that would implement [`handle_continue/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#c:handle_continue/2) and `{:stop, :normal, _}` gracefully from there after having its job done.

Comment: How interesting. Do you have any examples of that ? I have a hard time understanding how I could use it.

Comment: Example of what?

Comment: An example on how to use `start_phase`. I have trouble understanding how to use it in an app just by reading the docs.